# Storekit stopped working with iOS 16 SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased never called

Tags: ios, objective-c, storekit

Storekit stopped working with iOS 16. I start the payment, I'm prompted to enter the password, the payment is completed but `- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions` is never called for `SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased` so I can start the download.

How to solve this problem? Thank you!

Comment: Same here. Did you find the problem?

Comment: No, but I discovered that restarting the device would help in some cases. I'm still investigating the issue. I can't make StoreKit 2 work either. I think we should open a radar with Apple because everything works fine with iOS 15. This problem only happens with iOS 16.

Comment: Thank you. I'm trying StoreKit 2 right now. It should work with iOS 15 & 16.

Comment: Are you being able to make StoreKit 2 work?

Comment: At least when I call "AppStore.sync()" then it asks for user and password. I still need to understand some things, but it seems to work.

Comment: I can't make the buying sheet appear when I call let result = try await product.purchase()

Comment: Try this sample. It worked for me: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/implementing_a_store_in_your_app_using_the_storekit_api